# Authorization Bearer token in Apache Camel

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel, bearer-token

I want to use Apache Camel to call a rest webservice which takes a bearer token as authorization. I am getting 401 unauthorized access if I use the below code--

```java
@Component
public class LoadFileRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder{
    
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("timer:mytimer?repeatCount=1")
            .log("Scheduled job!")
            .to("direct:httpRoute");
            
        from("direct:httpRoute")
            .log("Http Route started")
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD).constant(HttpMethod.GET)
            .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
            .setHeader("Authorization").simple("Bearer "+ myToken)
            .to("https://my-rest-ws-url")
            .log("Response : ${body}");
    }   
}
```

I have also tried using process method to set the authorization token  exchange.getIn().setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+myToken); didn't work either.

Is it the correct way to send bearer token ?

Comment: I changed the camel version and it solved the problem.

Comment: which Apache Camel version do you used on this case ?

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```
Message message = exchange.getIn();
message.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
```

This works for me. I can see token in the Exchange properties. Apache Camel 2.7.5.

Slightly different though, is that I do it in a `.bean(SomeBean.class)` and then send to `toD()` with dynamic URL.

Comment: This works with version 4 as well.